# Java Swing mejorar el renderizado de fuentes

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, fuentes

## El problema

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Swing, pero la fuente se ve algo rara (hórrida desde mi punto de vista).

Aquí un ejemplo de una imagen sin aumento:

[image: Imagen de ejemplo sin aumento]

En los botones no se nota tanto, pero se nota mucho en el texto "Time for a 10m...", sobretodo en la letra e.

Esta es la imagen con aumento:

[image: Imagen de ejemplo con aumento]

Y se nota demasiado que no se renderiza muy bien, no se ven "suaves" las letras, como si no tuvieran lo que en inglés se le conoce como [**font anti aliasing**](https://smad.jmu.edu/shen/webtype/antialiasing.html).

## Lo que he intentado

Ya intenté

- Configurar variables para la JVM para utilizar font anti aliasing

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd"); // ya probé "lcd" y "on"
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
```

- Utilizar una fuente física diferente

```
Font SANS_SERIF_BOLD_12;
Font SANS_SERIF_BOLD_15;
try {
    Font niceSansSerifBold = Font.createFont(
        Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
        SWMain.getFileAsStream("/resources/fonts/SwanseaBold.ttf")
        // https://www.fontspace.com/swansea-font-f5873
    );
    SANS_SERIF_BOLD_12 = niceSansSerifBold.deriveFont(12f);
    SANS_SERIF_BOLD_15 = niceSansSerifBold.deriveFont(15f);
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    SANS_SERIF_BOLD_12 = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 12);
    SANS_SERIF_BOLD_15 = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 15);
}
```

Pero no funciona. Estoy seguro que en el último caso la fuente se carga bien, sin embargo el resultado es prácticamente el mismo.

[image: Imagen de ejemplo sin aumento 1]

Sucede lo mismo con una fuente *monospace*, inclusive se ve peor.

[image: Monospace font]

Ya sea que cargue una fuente física

```
Font MONOSPACE_BOLD_12;
Font MONOSPACE_BOLD_15;
try {
    Font niceMonospace = Font.createFont(
        Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
        SWMain.getFileAsStream("/resources/fonts/JetBrainsMono-Bold.ttf")
    );
    MONOSPACED_BOLD_12 = niceMonospace.deriveFont(12f);
    MONOSPACED_BOLD_24 = niceMonospace.deriveFont(24f);
}
```

O utilice una fuente lógica del sistema

```
catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    MONOSPACED_BOLD_12 = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 12);
    MONOSPACED_BOLD_24 = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 24);
}
```

### Últimas notas

Utilizo Fedora 33, con la versión de java:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

El problema también sucede con Fedora 32, y en Windows 10 (aunque no se nota tanto).

Espero me puedan ayudar a encontrar cómo hacer que las letras se rendericen bien, como por ejemplo en el navegador en prácticamente cualquier página, exampli gratia:

[image: SO]

El código completo de la aplicación está en [GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuksP.png).

Comment: Lo que has intentado de las propiedades del sistema, awt.useSystemAAFontSettings y swing.aatext, ¿has probado a pasarle esas propiedades como parámetro de la máquina virtual de Java en lugar de añadirlo en código? Es decir `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true`.

Comment: +1 @ordago, sí lo acabo de intentar y funcionó. No lo había intentado porque deseaba que la solución fuera 100% programática sin necesidad de agregar parámetros a la JVM. Pero eso me ayudó a encontrarle solución al problema, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;TR

Hay que setear las propiedades del sistema antes de que se utilice algún código referente a Swing o a AWT. En mi caso ponerlo al principio del método main funcionó correctamente

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd"); // use font antialiasing
    System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");

    // resto del código que utiliza AWT o Swing
}
```

### Explicación

Derivado del comentario por @ordago, intenté agregar parámetros a la JVM y funcionó, por lo que se me ocurrió una hipótesis de lo que podría estar pasando:

"Las propiedades del sistema no las estaba colocando antes de que la GUI se iniciara"

A pesar de que el código era el siguiente.

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd"); // use font antialiasing
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SWMain::new); // Crea el JFrame
```

Técnicamente ahí sí lo estaba agregando antes de que la GUI se iniciara, sin embargo, previo a ese código tenía el siguiente.

```
com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf.install();
```

Que instala el L&F [FlatLafDark](https://github.com/JFormDesigner/FlatLaf).

Por lo que entonces probé setear las variables antes de que se ejecutara dicho código y funcionó muy bien.

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd"); // use font antialiasing
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf.install();
```

#### Pruebas

Después decidí remover esa línea de código para utilizar únicamente código que yo había escrito y así estar seguro de que la hipótesis era cierta, e intenté lo siguiente:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    new SWMain(); // crea el JFrame, la primera línea de código que utiliza Swing
    System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd"); // use font antialiasing
    System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
});
```

El código anterior **NO** muestra los resultados deseados, porque las propiedades se setean **después** de que los componentes de Swing sean creados.

Sin embargo el código

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd"); // use font antialiasing
    System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
    new SWMain(); // crea el JFrame, la primera línea de código que utiliza Swing
});
```

**SÍ** muestra el resultado deseado, pues las propiedades se setean **antes** de que los componentes Swing hayan sido creados.

Y listo, problema solucionado, gracias @ordago.